# How do I multiply my lollipop production even more?

Tags: candy-box-2

I know that the Green Shark Fin and the Shell Powder help, but is there anything else I can use (besides hacks)?

Answer (score 2):

you can get the pitchfork in the darkroom in the castle I even got to 900 per second!